# Adding NSManagedObject to a global array

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsmutablearray, global

I'm trying to store the info into my global.category array but my NSLog shows that the count is 0 .
any idea why? or is it that array cannot add object of type NSmanagedObject?

```
 for (NSManagedObject *info in mutableFetchCategory)
{
    NSLog(@"sapphireID: %@", [info valueForKey:@"sapphireID"]);
    NSLog(@"category NAME/photo: %@", [info valueForKey:@"photo"]);
   [myGlobal.categoryArray addObject:info];
    NSLog(@"myglobal.categoryarray  count : %i",[myGlobal.categoryArray count]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly initialized `myGlobal` and `myGlobal.categoryArray` prior to calling this code?  If either is `nil` then you will get the behavior that you are seeing, because invoking any method on a `nil` instance returns `nil`, and logging `nil` as an integer will print "0", as shown here:

http://ideone.com/n05je

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be follows..

- "myGlobal.categoryArray" is nil.
- you can use "NSLog" outside of the "for"

Is this helpful?